# Como abrir um arquivo .fdb?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, arquivo, firebird

Preciso abrir um arquivo de banco de dados (`.fdb`), mas não sei como. O que devo fazer para abrir este arquivo?

Nele há uma lista que eu quero passar para o Excel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar qualquer linguagem que tenha suporte ao Firebird, ou pode usar um gerenciador para ele, como o [Flame Robin](http://www.flamerobin.org/), [InterBase Query](http://www.mitec.cz/ibq.html), [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/), [FenixSQL](http://fblib.altervista.org/), [Marathon](http://gmarathon.sourceforge.net/), [IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/) (conforme comentário abaixo), entre outros, opção não falta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: tem o ibexpert tbm

Comment: Bem lembrado, adicionado.

Comment: Estava meio perdido, pelo que pude entender o funcionamento de todos são bem semelhantes, Obrigado!

Comment: Um dos melhores e que eu uso é o IBExpert citado, além de ser um simples executável (que não exige instalação) é leve e completo!

Comment: ESF Database Migration Toolkit `pago`