# Ferramenta para Firebird - Quais

Tags: firebird

Qual seria o software mais utilizado para o gerenciamento de banco de dados firebird, se possível, me mostre opções free e pagas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como abrir um arquivo .fdb?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112883/como-abrir-um-arquivo-fdb)

Comment: Concordo com a resposta do @Guilherme Sanches IBExpert e um dos melhores , você pode também pode dar uma olhada no FlameRobin https://sourceforge.net/projects/flamerobin/

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, eu usei por muito tempo o IBExpert, na minha opinião é o melhor nesta área!
Ele executa praticamente tudo que você precisa em relação ao Firebird: Comparação de BD's com geração de script de diferença entre os dados, busca dinâmica de tabelas, triggers, procedures, backup, restore, etc

segue abaixo lista de quase todos gerenciador de BD Firebird disponíveis:

[Firebase Brasil](http://www.firebase.com.br/downloads.php?categ=2)

Segundo o próprio site, sobre o IBExpert:

"Mais um administrador de BD Interbase. Interface muito similar ao QuickDesk, mas contém alguns recursos à mais, como um "preenchedor de tabelas" para inserir dados de teste nas tabelas, um GRANT manager, etc... Suporta o IB 4,5 e 6 e Firebird 1.0. Possui uma versão FREE para substituir o IBConsole, uma versão educacional completa que funciona com bancos de até 50MB e a versão shareware com todos os recursos."

Existe a versão paga também com muito mais recursos...

Abraços :)

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas dentre elas são:

- [EMS SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird](https://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager)       Com versão Free e Paga.
- [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/)                                     Com versão Free e Paga.
- [Advanced Data Generator e Database Workbench](https://www.upscene.com) Com versão Free e Paga.

Acho o EMS SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird mais fácil de entender. Veja o que melhor se encaixa com sua preferencia.